# How to track memory allocation error in malloc in C

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault, malloc, valgrind

I am trying to allocate a memory to node in linked list using malloc function. However, I am getting segmentation fault on malloc call. I am unable to understand report generated by valgrind.

```
==28861==   total heap usage: 76 allocs, 73 frees, 14,544 bytes allocated
==28861== 
==28861== 48 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==28861==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==28861==    by 0x4027A2: create_server_entry_into_connection_list (all.c:734)
==28861==    by 0x401BF8: server_call (all.c:410)
==28861==    by 0x40103F: main (all.c:108)
==28861== 
==28861== 568 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==28861==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==28861==    by 0x3E3C260309: __fopen_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==28861==    by 0x4012E2: myip (all.c:174)
==28861==    by 0x400FE7: main (all.c:101)
==28861== 
==28861== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 3
==28861==    at 0x4A0610C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==28861==    by 0x4027B3: create_server_entry_into_connection_list (all.c:736)
==28861==    by 0x401BF8: server_call (all.c:410)
==28861==    by 0x40103F: main (all.c:108)
==28861== 
==28861== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28861==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28861==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28861==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28861==    still reachable: 1,640 bytes in 3 blocks
==28861==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28861== 
==28861== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28861== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==28861== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

Could anyone explain what can be reason behind such error.

Comment: line numbers are a good start... We don't know your code though

Comment: Actually its a very big code with many files connected so unable to post it here. I did checked those lines but seems like I have used those variables neatly. Also I read in valgrind report that Still reachable flag should not mess with your code while running but I am still getting a seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason? There are lots of possible reasons.

Try using `errno.h` it may be able to determine some problems.
`strerror(errno)` then returns the error as a string instead of a number.
Start with the first error from the debug console.. look at it carefully.

> total heap usage: 76 allocs, 73 frees, 14,544 bytes allocated

...I think you should restructure your code. This time pay more attention and test the program oftenly. 76 allocs, 73 frees. Only 14,544 bytes allocated?

Use tests such as `printf("p1 : %p\np2 : %p", pointer1, pointer2);` to investiage memory address. valgrind sometimes behaves weird. It is dependable.
If your code is too large.. maybe use hastebin.com to provide a common view of your code for us.

Don't typecast the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `still reachable` memory points towards the memory allocated to a global pointer and not being freed upon program completion. This does not always point to a memory leak. You can read more about that [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost).